# Where exactly should snort run?

Tags: intrusion-prevention

Apologies for this newbie question, but I am currently exploring IDS and snort is one that I see mentioned a lot. SO now I am looking at how to make use of it.

So let say I have a LAN and I need to monitor network traffic within that LAN, the question is, where exactly would I put snort? On another box that is connected to the LAN? if that is the case how would it then be able to monitor all traffic in the LAN.

I have been able set it up on a machine, but it only monitors traffic from the network adapter of that specific machine. I am trying to figure out how to move from that setup into one where it can monitor the whole LAN.

Any ideas?

Comment: We need more information in order to givr you a useful answer.  Please provide a simple diagram of your network, along with the types of infrastructure devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monitoring *all* traffic in a LAN isn't very practical, for performance reasons.

However, if your snort box has sufficient bandwidth and processing power then you need to make sure that all (interesting) traffic is actually sent that way. Using switched Ethernet only forwards frames where they are required - so by default, the box only sees its own traffic and broadcasts.

You need to configure the switch to mirror all (interesting) ports to the box's port; (*port mirroring, monitoring* or *SPAN*, depending in vendor). With some switches, a monitoring port becomes one way, so you might need a dedicated port on the switch and another NIC in the box. Of course, you need a managed switch with some kind of mirroring.

If you use more than one switch it may become complicated. First, you need to direct/monitor traffic across switches (e.g. using RSPAN) and second, the interconnect needs to be able to handle the traffic. Otherwise, the mirrored traffic might cause congestion which could cause production traffic to be dropped.

Alternatively, you could use dedicated interconnects for mirrored traffic (make sure you configure VLANs and spanning tree appropriately). Yet alternatively, with just a small number of switches in a single location, you might want to add NICs to your snort box and connect them all separately.